# Как сделать запрос в mysql таблицу с desc сортировкой?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Делаю запрос в базу mysql этой функцией:

```
$row = $this->wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM hm_open_links WHERE post_id=$id" );
```

Проблема в том, что выводится первый встретившийся запрос, а мне необходим последний записанный.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: SELECT * FROM hm_open_links WHERE post_id=$id ORDER BY post_id DESC

Comment: @StereoFlo Спасибо большое, с mysql очень редко работаю, забыл про ORDER BY совершенно... Работает так как нужно